# Image processing in Google App Engine

Tags: android, image, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee

I am trying to create an application server that does the following.

1. Get images from a user phone (once every 10 minutes).
2. Compare the new image with a reference image (pixel by pixel)

I managed to store an image using the Blobstore APIs. But I am only allowed to retrieve and display this image in a webpage(using the Blobkey). I wish to get the pixel data and implement an image difference algorithm on the server.

Is there a way this can be accomplished ? And is there a way to accomplish this without the use of blobs or database storage ? I can basically discard the new image once the comparison is done. I just need to store the reference image.

Answer (score 0):

You can load any file from the Blobstore if you know its key, and manipulate it anyway you want. For images it is as simple as:

```
Image referenceImage = ImagesServiceFactory.makeImageFromBlob(blobKey);
```

Take a look at [Images API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/), which is an App Engine service.